Probability involving 2 sets
It was a question from my student that I'm unable to solve and I was here seeking an answer in case I missed something. What is wrong with you people with DOWNVOTES?
In a class there are 12 students who like mathematics, 10 students who like physics, and 5 students who like both. If $4$ students are selected at random, calculate the probability of selecting at least $1$ student who likes physics.
How to solve this?
I get $10/17$. But I don't think that's correct. I didn't count the 4 students selection yet. What I did was drawing the Venn diagram with $2$ sets and it has one intersectio, i.e. in the middle is $5$ since $5$ people like both. Then it's clear that $7$ people onky like Maths and $5$ only like Physics. Altogether, $17$. And the event is the who likes physics i.e. there are $10$ people. As I said I haven't thought of $4$ students. My first thought was using combination. But how?

The problem isn't clear.  How many students dislike both?

If you are guessing that there are no students who dislike both then you need to ask: how many ways can we choose $4$ students with no restrictions? How many ways can we choose $4$ students who dislike Physics?

Does that mean students who like maths only? I.e. 7? So it would be $7$ choose $4$? Is that correct?

If you are guessing that there are no students who like neither, then yes.  But, honestly, that's just a wild guess to make the problem solvable. There's nothing in the problem statement that suggests that assumption.

Assuming there are a total of $12 + 10 - 5 = 17$ students, to find the probability that at least one of the four selected students likes physics, subtract the probability that all four of the selected students like only math from $1$.

Let us assume all students must like something, that is, $|S|=|M\cup P|$, where $S$ is the set of all students, and $M, P$ those among them who like math and physics, respectively.
It therefore seems that you only need the total number of students and those who like math. You can easily calculate that, as you correctly seem to have.
Now, notice that selecting at least one student who fulfills a criterion is equal to the complement of selecting none that do. In other words, you can equivalently (and much more easily) compute the probability of selecting absolutely no students in the $M$ set, and then complementing this probability. Formally,
$$\mathbb P\{\text{"At least one student in M"}\}=1-\mathbb P\{\text{"No students in M"}\}\,.$$
Let us now compute the latter. Also, it is easier to compute the number of combinations that fulfil our criterion, and then divide with all possible combinations to obtain the probability of the event. So, we need to think of how many ways you can pick one non-math liking student; once you do that, how many ways remain for us to pick the next, and so on.
To not select a student in the first draw, you have $|S\setminus M|$ ways. The next draw, however, leaves one less student in this group, so we now only have $|S\setminus M|-1$ students to pick from in order to fulfil our criterion. Let $n$ be the number of students in the positive set, i.e., $n=|S\setminus M|$, and $k$ the number of draws. We so far end up with
$$ \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\,.$$
However, we don't care about the order of the students, and in the way we acted we could have come with multiple ways to draw the very same students, just in different order. We therefore have to account for this multiplicity by dividing with the number of times we counted the same group. This multiplicity amounts to the permutations of the $k$ students in our pick, and equals $k!$. Indeed, we have $k$ ways to pick the first student out a single draw, then another $k-1$ for the second, and so on.
All in all, we care about the ways to pick $k$ students out of $n$ without the ordering playing a role; this number is given by the binomial coefficient
$${n \choose k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\,.$$
Now, the total number of selecting 4 students is given by the same rule, however now $n=|S|$ and $k=4$.
So, your probability to select no students in $M$ is
$$P\{\text{"No students in M"}\} = \frac{
{|S\setminus M|}\choose {k}
}{
{|S|}\choose {k}}\,.$$
Finally, to compute the probability you require, you take its complement.
If I make no mistake, you should get $1-\frac{35}{2380}=98.53\%$.
